# Angular property binding

Tags: angular, data-binding

Angular has different ways to data bind properties:

```
<img src="{{ myProperty }}">
<img bind-src="myProperty ">
<img [src]="myProperty">
```

Is there a correct way to bind component properties to the view? What is the difference between these three ways, when and why should I use each one?

Comment: Many answers can be found here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Interpolation and Property binding are virtually the same, and bind-src is just an alternate way that is wordy and not often used.

the **difference**:

**interpolation** "injects" the value into the html, so when you say
`value="{{ hello }}"` Angular is *inserting* your variable between the brackets.

**property binding** allows Angular to directly access the elements property in the html. this is a deeper access. When you say `[value]="hello"` Angular is grabbing the value property of the element, and *setting* your variable as that property's value.

**event binding** allows you to use events such as a click to trigger functions. these bindings use parenthesis for example `(click)="myFunction($event)"`. this will call the myFunction() method on defined in your .ts file. the parenthesis around '(click)' bind the function to the dom event.`$event` is a keyword passing the event object to the function. you could also pass a string with single quotes, or even a variable with interpolation.

**Two way (data) binding** allows you to have an event combined with a property binding. For example

```
<input [(ngModel)]="username">
<p>Hello {{username}}!</p>
```

will allow you to have an input and display the value at the same time. learn more [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html)

**Lastly** when to use interpolation and when to use data-binding. This is usually a formality, typically when using a smart component and dumb (presentation) component, you would bind to the html with property binding because of readability, and because it is shall I say, "more secure" to bind to a property in that case. If you have simple values, then maybe interpolation is your friend. It all comes down to readability, best practice, and preference.

Answer (score 1):

See [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-)

and [binding or interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation)

> Interpolation is a convenient alternative to property binding in many cases.
>
> When rendering data values as strings, there is no technical reason to
>   prefer one form to the other. You lean toward readability, which tends
>   to favor interpolation. You suggest establishing coding style rules
>   and choosing the form that both conforms to the rules and feels most
>   natural for the task at hand.
>
> When setting an element property to a non-string data value, you must
>   use property binding.

Answer (score 1):

They are all pretty similar, one way data binding.

I think src="{{ myProperty }}" is slightly different because it will always render a string, so if you needed an int or boolean it might not work quite right.

I know in angularjs this type of syntax binding could cause compatibility issues with older versions of IE. I'm not sure if those have been resolved in Angular 2+, but that's another reason I might avoid src="{{ myProperty }}"

The other two are identical. The community seems to prefer  but its a preference.