# Angular reactive form in array, how to get formcontrolnames?

Tags: angular

```html
<div *ngFor="let reply of repliesForm?.get('replies')?.value; let i = index;">
    <div [innerHTML]="reply.body"></div>
    <textarea formControlName="reply.body"></textarea>
</div>
```

The innerHTML is set fine but how do I get the `formControlName` to bind to the textarea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular property binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368382/angular-property-binding)

Comment: Can you please share your ts code of reactive Form, So that I can figure out your problem

Comment: can you share your typescript file

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your loop like this. Because you can access both value and control.

```html
<div *ngFor="let replyControl of repliesForm?.get('replies'); let i = index;">
    <div [innerHTML]="replyControl.value.body"></div>
    <textarea [formControl]="replyControl"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: But the textarea is not bound to the body here

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work fine for you

```
<div *ngFor="let reply of repliesForm?.get('replies')?.value; let i = index;">
  <div [innerHTML]="reply.body"></div>
  <textarea formControlName="{{reply.body}}"></textarea>
</div>
```