# Angular: Mat-Progress-Spinner does not recognize indeterminate mode when updating from Angular 9/10 to 13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am updating my Angular app from 9/10 to 13 and I've been following the [official documentation here](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/examples). I rewrote my old code accordingly to fit the new convention:

```
<mat-progress-spinner
    [color]="primary"
    [mode]="indeterminate">
  </mat-progress-spinner>
```

But apparently this does not compile...
The error I get is:

```
error TS2339: Property 'indeterminate' does not exist on type 'ComponentNameHere'.
```

Yes, I've imported the Mat-Progress-Spinner already in module.ts

**UPDATE**

If I remove the brackets from color and mode I get the following error:

```
error NG8001: 'mat-progress-spinner' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-progress-spinner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-progress-spinner' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

**UPDATE 2**

My module.ts looks like the following:

```
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
...
 imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
        Ng2SearchPipeModule,
        NgMatSearchBarModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        WavesModule,
        InputsModule,
        ButtonsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatTreeModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        ModalModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        // Mat-Slide-Toggle
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        ...
```

Comment: It's `mode="indeterminate"`, not `[mode]="indeterminate"`.

Comment: @jabaa then it doesn't recognize the component at all...

Comment: What does _"I rewrote my old code accordingly to fit the new convention"_ mean? What was the old convention and what is the new convention?

Comment: I can't reproduce your statements. The code from my first comments works: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogress-spinner-overview-example.html

Comment: I think I only added the brackets and that's about it. The StackBlitz link is invalid btw.

Comment: Why did you add the brackets? It's not a convention. It has nothing to do with new and old. The brackets have a function and a meaning and they had the same meaning 2017 in Angular 2. `mode="indeterminate"` is not `[mode]="indeterminate"`. A new link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ibsiu?file=src/app/progress-spinner-overview-example.html

Comment: This is not a real duplicate but it explains the difference: [Angular property binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368382/angular-property-binding), [What is the difference between parentheses, brackets and asterisks in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2) The second link is from 2016 and still valid. It's also explained in https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax

Comment: You're right, I don't need the brackets. How do I fix the error then?

Comment: What error? The error should be gone after you remove the brackets. You can see the code in my Stackblitz link. It works and there is no error.

Comment: The error message means you didn't import the module. The code in your question is correct except the brackets. Currently, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @jabaa that what I understood too, but clearly I did import the module. You can check out my updated question to see that

Comment: A [mcve] in form of a Stackblitz would be helpful. Maybe you need to rebuild the dependencies.

Comment: @jabaa I've made this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgd7sl but my predefined themes for @angular/material seem to throw `Error in src/styles.scss
Missing "./fesm2015/material.mjs" export in "@angular/material" package` and I seem to fail to fix it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific programming questions. It doesn't work well with interactive debugging. There are other platforms with screen and file sharing and live chat.

Comment: I commented out the content of `style.scss` and it works. This question already asks about Angular property-binding, Angular module imports and SCSS. That's not a specific programming question.

Comment: Ok, I tried commenting `styles.scss` out but no loading animation appears to me. Weird. Also if it does work, the MRE is identical to the original code I'm having so this is super weird...

Comment: How could someone help you as long as you can't provide a [mcve]? There seems to be something weird going on on your system and the code is correct.

Comment: I did provide a MRE here in the comments. Maybe I messed something up by forcing updates when updating with `ng` and `npm`? Any idea how to further debug this?

Comment: You have a working example. Download it and compare the working example with your actual code. Find the difference that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I needed to remove the `[]` brackets from the bindings and it seems that some removed packages (due to no longer being maintained for newer versions of Angular) caused the issue. Commented out their imports and the app seems to magically work.

I removed (by commenting out) the `ng-docx`, `angular-bootstrap-md` and `ng-mat-search-bar` packages.

Comment: This answer isn't really useful or at least I can't see how this could help future users solve their problem.

Comment: @jabaa the solution is to remove package imports for packages that got removed when upgrading the Angular version, what's not clear about it and how come it's not useful? If I formulated it badly so that it's hard to comprehend, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: You could list the packages, but this answer isn't useful, because the packages aren't listed in the question. That makes the useless, too, because it's not answerable.

Comment: What are the chances that the people that stumbled upon this question have the very same packages?! Also it applies to EVERY package that is no longer maintained and not supported by newer versions of Angular making such information completely useless

Comment: IMO the question and answer are useless because the question doesn't contain enough details to be answerable.

Comment: I named the packages anyways, but it's not like it matters.

Comment: @jabaa saying what exactly is lacking in the question would be more useful than just vaguely saying that it "doesn't contain enough details"

Comment: I only wanted to explain downvotes. There is probably not much you could do to improve it. You were not able to create a [mcve]. The problem is outdated packages, but the packages aren't listed in the question. The question title mentions the spinner. How is this answer related to the spinner or to property binding?

Comment: Because the error, among others, contains the spinner.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the original question and the error message `error TS2339: Property 'indeterminate' does not exist on type 'ComponentNameHere'.` The original question was a duplicate and the problem was wrong property binding. Now, you're trying to recycle the question and that's also not recommended. The best thing is to rollback the updates or delete this question and ask a new one. This answer doesn't answer the question in the title and it doesn't solve the problem in the top of the description.

Comment: Edited the answer, is this sufficient now?

Comment: The question contains 2 or even 3 unrelated problems. The first part is a 6 year old duplicate. Missing research effort is a downvote reason for questions. The problem(s) in the first and second update aren't reproducible. I don't see any worth in this answer. The first part is answered multiple times in a much better way. That's a downvote reason for answers.